# What are the different document ID types for documents in the DocuSign API?

Tags: docusignapi

So far I've seen numeric-like IDs (`"1"`), `"portfolio"`, and `"certificate"`. The [eSignature API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/list/#schema_200_envelopedocumentsresult_envelopedocumentsresult_envelopedocuments_documentid) doesn't go into more details, aside from *'The ID of the document that the tab is placed on. This value must refer to the ID of an existing document.'*

Is there any name IDs (such as `"portfolio"`) that one should be aware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values that documentId can take are listed [here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/get/) under "Path Parameters". There are a few reserved keywords but otherwise they would be integral values from 1, based on the documentId that you've set while creating the envelope. (defaults from 1 onwards)

Comment: It never occurred to me to look at that method. Thanks a lot, Karan :)